# Uncontextualized square root of $\nu$ over a Euclidian norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes

I have not seen this v show up anywhere else in the paper, and then it pops up here. What would it be?
[Full paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04056.pdf)

$$\min\left[1, \frac{\sqrt{v}}{\|\mathbf{W}_i,\cdot\|_2} \right]$$

Can I assume this is an Euclidian norm operation on the row $i$? Why is the two in subscript?

The original notation from the paper is

[image: Original equation]

Comment: Typically $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the $p$-norm.  For vector $v = (v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_n)$, this would be the value $\|v\|_p = \sqrt[p]{|v_1|^p + |v_2|^p + \dotsb + |v_n|^p}$.  With $p=2$, we recover the usual Euclidean norm.  That being said, I don't have the energy to read through that entire paper to find the equation that you are interested in and parse all of the notation leading up to it.  It would be helpful if you added some details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper explains it perfectly:

"...where $\nu \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is a regularization parameter...", that is, a scalar parameter that governs the "smoothness" of a function.  It is basically the length of the weight vector; the smaller that length, the simpler and smoother the function.

The "2" in $\| \cdot \|_2$ means the squared norm, i.e., $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots}$.  If it had be an "3", then $\sqrt[3]{x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \ldots }$